# how can I make my django app automatically scrape in the background on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis

I am trying to figure out how to have my app use a function that scrapes sites in the backround, becuase it takes a long time and causes an error if ran in the foreground. So I followed the tutorial on Heroku's site that has a function that counts words and is ran in the background. It works. So I was ready to put my function in there via import at first. So I imported it and created a function that use it. I got this traceback

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_raddqueue.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src.blog.my_task import conn, is_page_ok
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/src/blog/my_task.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .my_scraps import p_panties
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/src/blog/my_scraps.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import Post
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/src/blog/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/taggit/managers.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 159, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 160, in ContentType
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I even tried to create the function in my_task.py ran it and got the same traceback

this is my file structure

[image]

below are the files and the code I think is relevant to the reproduction of the problem

the function I want to use located in my_scraps.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from .models import Post
import random
import re
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import os

def p_panties():
    def swappo():
        user_one = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" '
        user_two = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)" '
        user_thr = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" '
        user_for = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0" '

        agent_list = [user_one, user_two, user_thr, user_for]
        a = random.choice(agent_list)
        return a

    headers = {
        "user-agent": swappo(),
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "accept-charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    }

    pan_url = 'http://www.example.org'
    shtml = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(shtml.text, 'html5lib')
    video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'post-start'})
    name = 'pan videos'

    if os.getenv('_system_name') == 'OSX':
        author = User.objects.get(id=2)
    else:
        author = User.objects.get(id=3)

    def youtube_link(url):
        youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soupdata.find_all('p')[0]
        entries = [{'text': div,
                    } for div in video_row]
        tubby = str(entries[0]['text'])
        urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', tubby)
        cleaned_url = urls[0].replace('?&amp;autoplay=1', '')
        return cleaned_url

    def yt_id(code):
        the_id = code
        youtube_id = the_id.replace('https://www.youtube.com/embed/', '')
        return youtube_id

    def strip_hd(hd, move):
        str = hd
        new_hd = str.replace(move, '')
        return new_hd

    entries = [{'href': div.a.get('href'),
                'text': strip_hd(strip_hd(div.h2.text, '– Official video HD'), '– Oficial video HD').lstrip(),
                'embed': youtube_link(div.a.get('href')), 
                'comments': strip_hd(strip_hd(div.h2.text, '– Official video HD'), '– Oficial video HD').lstrip(),
                'src': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + yt_id(youtube_link(div.a.get('href'))) + '/maxresdefault.jpg', 
                'name': name,
                'url': div.a.get('href'),
                'author': author,
                'video': True

                } for div in video_row][:13]

    for entry in entries:
        post = Post()
        post.title = entry['text']
        title = post.title
        if not Post.objects.filter(title=title):
            post.title = entry['text']
            post.name = entry['name']
            post.url = entry['url']
            post.body = entry['comments']
            post.image_url = entry['src']
            post.video_path = entry['embed']
            post.author = entry['author']
            post.video = entry['video']
            post.status = 'draft'
            post.save()
            post.tags.add("video", "Musica")
    return entries
```

my_task.py

```
    import os

    import redis
    from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection
    from .my_scraps import p_panties
    import requests


    listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

    redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

    conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with Connection(conn):
            worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
            worker.work()


    def is_page_ok(url):
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return "{0} is up".format(url)
        else:
            return "{0} is not OK. Status {1}".format(url, response.status_code)


    def do_this():
        a = p_panties()
        return a
```

my_raddqueue.py

```
from rq import Queue
    from src.blog.my_task import conn, do_this

    q = Queue('important', connection=conn)

    result = q.enqueue(do_this)

    print("noted")
```

this line

```
from .my_scraps import p_panties
```

will cause that traceback as well even if I'm not using it. After I gave up trying to use the functionI was trying to use and see if the other one worked, they didn't and I couldnt figure out why until I started deleting or commenting things out one by one when I commented or deleted this line out it worked. What is my Issue. all I want to do is have my app scrape at predesignated times of the day in my heroku app. How can I achieve this? Is my approach here all wrong? Ive seen something called APSscheduler SHOULD I be using that instead. Any input on improving my code would be appreciated. haven't been coding that long. A lot of this came from my own head so if it looks unprofessional that's why thanks you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about Heroku. But normally you can achieve such automated tasks in django through Celery.

You have awesome documentation here. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: it caps at python 3.3 I'm currently using 3.5. i'm starting to see a pattern developing. The latest is not the greatest because it's the latest. a lot of new code doesn't work with certain libraries

Comment: I see it's different on git hub than from the link you provided. on github it says it supports 3.5. I'll check it out when I get back. I hope it works